# Can a sheaf be nailed by the restrictions on an open covering?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety and $\{U_i\}$ be an open covering of $X$. Consider two sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ such that
$$\mathcal{F}|_{U_i}\cong\mathcal{G}|_{U_i}$$
for any $i$, could we say that $\mathcal{F}\cong\mathcal{G}$? If not, what kind of additional conditions can make it ture?

Comment: i think the necessary additional condition is that these isomorphisms agree on intersections, see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04TN

Comment: No. Otherwise, all invertible sheaves are the same. Then the Picard group is boring. I think the misconception comes from this statement: A sheaf morphism $\varphi:\mathscr F\to \mathscr G$ is an isomorphism if and only if it is stalkwise. The problem is sheaves locally are isomorphic in non-canonical way, but these isomorphisms does not come from a global one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure about the case of a variety. But if we let $X$ be the projective line $\mathbb{RP}_1$, we can consider the sheaf of sections of the canonical quotient map $S^1 \to X$, where $S_1$ is the circle. This sheaf is locally isomorphic to $2$; however, it does not have any global elements and is therefore not globally isomorphic.